# Firebase exception with Android eclipse

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am saving an image to Firebase as a String. For this I encode it as a Base64 String. Than have some fields in it.

```
myfirebaselink
     user
      employee
        -KAZY5627P4MjLBa3Ae-
          DateTime: "2016-02-15 16:18:20"
          Latitude: "11.0318354"
          Longitude: "11.0318354"
          Path: "base64string"
          Seqno: "1"
       -KAZZcBscTCAon8ShoXa
          DateTime: "2016-02-15 16:25:02"
          Latitude: "11.0318501"
          Longitude: "11.0318501"
          Path: "base64string"
          Seqno: "2"
```

the base64 string length is 3279272 like tat.

```
    02-22 13:50:00.250: E/RunLoop(26517): Uncaught exception in Firebase runloop (2.5.0). Please report to support@firebase.com
    02-22 13:50:00.250: E/RunLoop(26517): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    02-22 13:50:00.250: E/RunLoop(26517):   at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.<init>(AbstractStringBuilder.java:82)
    02-22 13:50:00.250: E/RunLoop(26517):   at java.lang.StringBuilder.<init>(StringBuilder.java:67)
    02-22 13:50:00.250: E/RunLoop(26517):   at com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.TextBuffer.contentsAsString(TextBuffer.java:350)
    02-22 13:50:00.250: E/RunLoop(26517):   at com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.getText(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:207)
    02-22 13:50:00.250: E/RunLoop(26517):   at com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.UntypedObjectDeserializer.deserialize(UntypedObjectDeserializer.java:59)
    02-22 13:50:00.250: E/RunLoop(26517):   at com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.UntypedObjectDeserializer.mapObject(UntypedObjectDeserializer.java:225)
    02-22 13:50:00.250: E/RunLoop(26517):   at com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.UntypedObjectDeserializer.deserialize(UntypedObjectDeserializer.java:51)
    02-22 13:50:00.250: E/RunLoop(26517):   at com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.UntypedObjectDeserializer.mapObject(UntypedObjectDeserializer.java:225)
    02-22 13:50:00.250: E/RunLoop(26517):   at com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.UntypedObjectDeserializer.deserialize(UntypedObjectDeserializer.java:51)
    02-22 13:50:00.250: E/RunLoop(26517):   at com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.UntypedObjectDeserializer.mapObject(UntypedObjectDeserializer.java:211)
    02-22 13:50:00.250: E/RunLoop(26517):   at com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.UntypedObjectDeserializer.deserialize(UntypedObjectDeserializer.java:51)
    02-22 13:50:00.250: E/RunLoop(26517):   at com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.UntypedObjectDeserializer.mapObject(UntypedObjectDeserializer.java:203)
    02-22 13:50:00.250: E/RunLoop(26517):   at com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.UntypedObjectDeserializer.deserialize(UntypedObjectDeserializer.java:51)
    02-22 13:50:00.250: E/RunLoop(26517):   at com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer._readAndBindStringMap(MapDeserializer.java:432)
    02-22 13:50:00.250: E/RunLoop(26517):   at com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:314)
    02-22 13:50:00.250: E/RunLoop(26517):   at com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:26)
    02-22 13:50:00.250: E/RunLoop(26517):   at com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2888)
    02-22 13:50:00.250: E/RunLoop(26517):   at com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2071)
    02-22 13:50:00.250: E/RunLoop(26517):   at com.firebase.client.realtime.WebsocketConnection.appendFrame(WebsocketConnection.java:221)
    02-22 13:50:00.250: E/RunLoop(26517):   at com.firebase.client.realtime.WebsocketConnection.handleIncomingFrame(WebsocketConnection.java:265)
    02-22 13:50:00.250: E/RunLoop(26517):   at com.firebase.client.realtime.WebsocketConnection.access$500(WebsocketConnection.java:27)
    02-22 13:50:00.250: E/RunLoop(26517):   at com.firebase.client.realtime.WebsocketConnection$WSClientTubesock$2.run(WebsocketConnection.java:72)
    02-22 13:50:00.250: E/RunLoop(26517):   at com.firebase.client.utilities.DefaultRunLoop$1.run(DefaultRunLoop.java:54)
    02-22 13:50:00.250: E/RunLoop(26517):   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
    02-22 13:50:00.250: E/RunLoop(26517):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    02-22 13:50:00.250: E/RunLoop(26517):   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152)
    02-22 13:50:00.250: E/RunLoop(26517):   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265)
    02-22 13:50:00.250: E/RunLoop(26517):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    02-22 13:50:00.250: E/RunLoop(26517):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    02-22 13:50:00.250: E/RunLoop(26517):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
    02-22 13:50:00.250: D/AndroidRuntime(26517): Shutting down VM
    02-22 13:50:00.250: W/dalvikvm(26517): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x417bad88)
    02-22 13:50:00.260: E/RunLoop(26517): Uncaught exception in Firebase runloop (2.5.0). Please report to support@firebase.com
    02-22 13:50:00.260: E/RunLoop(26517): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Trying to add string after reading
    02-22 13:50:00.260: E/RunLoop(26517):   at com.firebase.client.realtime.util.StringListReader.addString(StringListReader.java:28)
    02-22 13:50:00.260: E/RunLoop(26517):   at com.firebase.client.realtime.WebsocketConnection.appendFrame(WebsocketConnection.java:215)
    02-22 13:50:00.260: E/RunLoop(26517):   at com.firebase.client.realtime.WebsocketConnection.handleIncomingFrame(WebsocketConnection.java:265)
    02-22 13:50:00.260: E/RunLoop(26517):   at com.firebase.client.realtime.WebsocketConnection.access$500(WebsocketConnection.java:27)
    02-22 13:50:00.260: E/RunLoop(26517):   at com.firebase.client.realtime.WebsocketConnection$WSClientTubesock$2.run(WebsocketConnection.java:72)
    02-22 13:50:00.260: E/RunLoop(26517):   at com.firebase.client.utilities.DefaultRunLoop$1.run(DefaultRunLoop.java:54)
    02-22 13:50:00.260: E/RunLoop(26517):   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
    02-22 13:50:00.260: E/RunLoop(26517):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    02-22 13:50:00.260: E/RunLoop(26517):   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152)
    02-22 13:50:00.260: E/RunLoop(26517):   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265)
    02-22 13:50:00.260: E/RunLoop(26517):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    02-22 13:50:00.260: E/RunLoop(26517):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    02-22 13:50:00.260: E/RunLoop(26517):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
    02-22 13:50:00.260: E/RunLoop(26517): Uncaught exception in Firebase runloop (2.5.0). Please report to support@firebase.com
    02-22 13:50:00.260: E/RunLoop(26517): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Trying to add string after reading
    02-22 13:50:00.260: E/RunLoop(26517):   at com.firebase.client.realtime.util.StringListReader.addString(StringListReader.java:28)
    02-22 13:50:00.260: E/RunLoop(26517):   at com.firebase.client.realtime.WebsocketConnection.appendFrame(WebsocketConnection.java:215)
    02-22 13:50:00.260: E/RunLoop(26517):   at com.firebase.client.realtime.WebsocketConnection.handleIncomingFrame(WebsocketConnection.java:265)
    02-22 13:50:00.260: E/RunLoop(26517):   at com.firebase.client.realtime.WebsocketConnection.access$500(WebsocketConnection.java:27)
    02-22 13:50:00.260: E/RunLoop(26517):   at com.firebase.client.realtime.WebsocketConnection$WSClientTubesock$2.run(WebsocketConnection.java:72)
    02-22 13:50:00.260: E/RunLoop(26517):   at com.firebase.client.utilities.DefaultRunLoop$1.run(DefaultRunLoop.java:54)
    02-22 13:50:00.260: E/RunLoop(26517):   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
    02-22 13:50:00.260: E/RunLoop(26517):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    02-22 13:50:00.260: E/RunLoop(26517):   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152)
    02-22 13:50:00.260: E/RunLoop(26517):   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265)
    02-22 13:50:00.260: E/RunLoop(26517):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    02-22 13:50:00.260: E/RunLoop(26517):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    02-22 13:50:00.260: E/RunLoop(26517):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
    02-22 13:50:00.260: E/RunLoop(26517): Uncaught exception in Firebase runloop (2.5.0). Please report to support@firebase.com
    02-22 13:50:00.260: E/RunLoop(26517): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Trying to add string after reading
    02-22 13:50:00.260: E/RunLoop(26517):   at com.firebase.client.realtime.util.StringListReader.addString(StringListReader.java:28)
    02-22 13:50:00.260: E/RunLoop(26517):   at com.firebase.client.realtime.WebsocketConnection.appendFrame(WebsocketConnection.java:215)
    02-22 13:50:00.260: E/RunLoop(26517):   at com.firebase.client.realtime.WebsocketConnection.handleIncomingFrame(WebsocketConnection.java:265)
    02-22 13:50:00.260: E/RunLoop(26517):   at com.firebase.client.realtime.WebsocketConnection.access$500(WebsocketConnection.java:27)
    02-22 13:50:00.260: E/RunLoop(26517):   at com.firebase.client.realtime.WebsocketConnection$WSClientTubesock$2.run(WebsocketConnection.java:72)
    02-22 13:50:00.260: E/RunLoop(26517):   at com.firebase.client.utilities.DefaultRunLoop$1.run(DefaultRunLoop.java:54)
    02-22 13:50:00.260: E/RunLoop(26517):   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
    02-22 13:50:00.260: E/RunLoop(26517):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    02-22 13:50:00.260: E/RunLoop(26517):   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152)
    02-22 13:50:00.260: E/RunLoop(26517):   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265)
    02-22 13:50:00.260: E/RunLoop(26517):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    02-22 13:50:00.260: E/RunLoop(26517):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    02-22 13:50:00.260: E/RunLoop(26517):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
    02-22 13:50:00.260: E/RunLoop(26517): Uncaught exception in Firebase runloop (2.5.0). Please report to support@firebase.com
    02-22 13:50:00.260: E/RunLoop(26517): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Trying to add string after reading
    02-22 13:50:00.260: E/RunLoop(26517):   at com.firebase.client.realtime.util.StringListReader.addString(StringListReader.java:28)
    02-22 13:50:00.260: E/RunLoop(26517):   at com.firebase.client.realtime.WebsocketConnection.appendFrame(WebsocketConnection.java:215)
    02-22 13:50:00.260: E/RunLoop(26517):   at com.firebase.client.realtime.WebsocketConnection.handleIncomingFrame(WebsocketConnection.java:265)
    02-22 13:50:00.260: E/RunLoop(26517):   at com.firebase.client.realtime.WebsocketConnection.access$500(WebsocketConnection.java:27)
    02-22 13:50:00.260: E/RunLoop(26517):   at com.firebase.client.realtime.WebsocketConnection$WSClientTubesock$2.run(WebsocketConnection.java:72)
    02-22 13:50:00.260: E/RunLoop(26517):   at com.firebase.client.utilities.DefaultRunLoop$1.run(DefaultRunLoop.java:54)
    02-22 13:50:00.260: E/RunLoop(26517):   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
    02-22 13:50:00.260: E/RunLoop(26517):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    02-22 13:50:00.260: E/RunLoop(26517):   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152)
    02-22 13:50:00.260: E/RunLoop(26517):   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265)
    02-22 13:50:00.260: E/RunLoop(26517):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    02-22 13:50:00.260: E/RunLoop(26517):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    02-22 13:50:00.260: E/RunLoop(26517):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
    02-22 13:50:00.270: E/AndroidRuntime(26517): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    02-22 13:50:00.270: E/AndroidRuntime(26517): Process: com.androidbegin.splashtutorial, PID: 26517
    02-22 13:50:00.270: E/AndroidRuntime(26517): java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncaught exception in Firebase runloop (2.5.0). Please report to support@firebase.com
    02-22 13:50:00.270: E/AndroidRuntime(26517):    at com.firebase.client.android.AndroidPlatform$1$1.run(AndroidPlatform.java:49)
    02-22 13:50:00.270: E/AndroidRuntime(26517):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    02-22 13:50:00.270: E/AndroidRuntime(26517):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    02-22 13:50:00.270: E/AndroidRuntime(26517):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
    02-22 13:50:00.270: E/AndroidRuntime(26517):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5151)
    02-22 13:50:00.270: E/AndroidRuntime(26517):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    02-22 13:50:00.270: E/AndroidRuntime(26517):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    02-22 13:50:00.270: E/AndroidRuntime(26517):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:875)
    02-22 13:50:00.270: E/AndroidRuntime(26517):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:691)
    02-22 13:50:00.270: E/AndroidRuntime(26517):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    02-22 13:50:00.270: E/AndroidRuntime(26517): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    02-22 13:50:00.270: E/AndroidRuntime(26517):    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.<init>(AbstractStringBuilder.java:82)
    02-22 13:50:00.270: E/AndroidRuntime(26517):    at java.lang.StringBuilder.<init>(StringBuilder.java:67)
    02-22 13:50:00.270: E/AndroidRuntime(26517):    at com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.TextBuffer.contentsAsString(TextBuffer.java:350)
    02-22 13:50:00.270: E/AndroidRuntime(26517):    at com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.getText(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:207)
    02-22 13:50:00.270: E/AndroidRuntime(26517):    at com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.UntypedObjectDeserializer.deserialize(UntypedObjectDeserializer.java:59)
    02-22 13:50:00.270: E/AndroidRuntime(26517):    at com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.UntypedObjectDeserializer.mapObject(UntypedObjectDeserializer.java:225)
    02-22 13:50:00.270: E/AndroidRuntime(26517):    at com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.UntypedObjectDeserializer.deserialize(UntypedObjectDeserializer.java:51)
    02-22 13:50:00.270: E/AndroidRuntime(26517):    at com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.UntypedObjectDeserializer.mapObject(UntypedObjectDeserializer.java:225)
    02-22 13:50:00.270: E/AndroidRuntime(26517):    at com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.UntypedObjectDeserializer.deserialize(UntypedObjectDeserializer.java:51)
    02-22 13:50:00.270: E/AndroidRuntime(26517):    at com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.UntypedObjectDeserializer.mapObject(UntypedObjectDeserializer.java:211)
    02-22 13:50:00.270: E/AndroidRuntime(26517):    at com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.UntypedObjectDeserializer.deserialize(UntypedObjectDeserializer.java:51)
    02-22 13:50:00.270: E/AndroidRuntime(26517):    at com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.UntypedObjectDeserializer.mapObject(UntypedObjectDeserializer.java:203)
    02-22 13:50:00.270: E/AndroidRuntime(26517):    at com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.UntypedObjectDeserializer.deserialize(UntypedObjectDeserializer.java:51)
    02-22 13:50:00.270: E/AndroidRuntime(26517):    at com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer._readAndBindStringMap(MapDeserializer.java:432)
    02-22 13:50:00.270: E/AndroidRuntime(26517):    at com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:314)
    02-22 13:50:00.270: E/AndroidRuntime(26517):    at com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:26)
    02-22 13:50:00.270: E/AndroidRuntime(26517):    at com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2888)
    02-22 13:50:00.270: E/AndroidRuntime(26517):    at com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2071)
    02-22 13:50:00.270: E/AndroidRuntime(26517):    at com.firebase.client.realtime.WebsocketConnection.appendFrame(WebsocketConnection.java:221)
    02-22 13:50:00.270: E/AndroidRuntime(26517):    at com.firebase.client.realtime.WebsocketConnection.handleIncomingFrame(WebsocketConnection.java:265)
    02-22 13:50:00.270: E/AndroidRuntime(26517):    at com.firebase.client.realtime.WebsocketConnection.access$500(WebsocketConnection.java:27)
    02-22 13:50:00.270: E/AndroidRuntime(26517):    at com.firebase.client.realtime.WebsocketConnection$WSClientTubesock$2.run(WebsocketConnection.java:72)
    02-22 13:50:00.270: E/AndroidRuntime(26517):    at com.firebase.client.utilities.DefaultRunLoop$1.run(DefaultRunLoop.java:54)
    02-22 13:50:00.270: E/AndroidRuntime(26517):    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
    02-22 13:50:00.270: E/AndroidRuntime(26517):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    02-22 13:50:00.270: E/AndroidRuntime(26517):    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152)
    02-22 13:50:00.270: E/AndroidRuntime(26517):    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265)
    02-22 13:50:00.270: E/AndroidRuntime(26517):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    02-22 13:50:00.270: E/AndroidRuntime(26517):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    02-22 13:50:00.270: E/AndroidRuntime(26517):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
    02-22 13:50:03.590: I/Process(26517): Sending signal. PID: 26517 SIG: 9
    02-22 13:50:04.030: I/Adreno-EGL(29504): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  ()
    02-22 13:50:04.030: I/Adreno-EGL(29504): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.14
    02-22 13:50:04.030: I/Adreno-EGL(29504): Build Date: 08/12/14 Tue
    02-22 13:50:04.030: I/Adreno-EGL(29504): Local Branch: 3.5.1_RB1_43_new
    02-22 13:50:04.030: I/Adreno-EGL(29504): Remote Branch: 
    02-22 13:50:04.030: I/Adreno-EGL(29504): Local Patches: 
    02-22 13:50:04.030: I/Adreno-EGL(29504): Reconstruct Branch: 
    02-22 13:50:04.190: D/OpenGLRenderer(29504): Enabling debug mode 0
    02-22 13:50:04.320: I/ActivityManager(29504): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@426b45f0 time:406679141
```

please anyone give me solution. thank you in advance

**EDITED**

```
Query queryRef = rootRef.orderByValue().limitToFirst(1);
        queryRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChild) {
                tv1.append("retrieving");
            //  BlogPost facts = snapshot.getValue(BlogPost.class);
            //Integer s1 = (int) snapshot.getChildrenCount();           
        //tv1.append(s1.toString());
                String myImageData=(String) snapshot.getValue();
                byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(myImageData.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);

                  image.setImageBitmap(
                          BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length)
                  );
                System.out.println(snapshot.getValue() );

            }
```

This above code returns the Path, I gave firebase link as myfirebaselink.com//user/employee/-KAZY5627P4MjLBa3Ae- So only under -KAZY5627P4MjLBa3Ae- path is retrieving. 
if i give link until employee it doesn't retrieving the child. 
I need to get Path from both , how should i code ?

Comment: Can you add the code that is causing this error?

Comment: Your app is using too much memory, leading to an `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`. The fact that you're loading base64 encoded images from a database, probably contributes to this problem. The solution is to load fewer images, or smaller images, or no images at all.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35143220/firebase-java-lang-outofmemoryerror, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35428380/firebase-datasnapshot-out-of-memory-error and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33367502/out-of-memory-error-using-firebase